# Mongoose ObjectID not working as argument in function

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to edit a `div`'s `innerHTML`, using the `div`'s id. I have a bunch of `div`s, as my site is a social network, so there are a lot of posts, each in it's own `div`. This is my code:

```
<a onclick="Like({{id}}, {{likes}}, {{dislikes}});" class="btn btn-like"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
    <p id="{{id}}">{{likes}} likes | {{dislikes}} dislikes</p>

   <script>
    function Like(id, likes, dislikes){
     alert(likes);
     document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = likes + 1 + " likes | " + dislikes + " dislikes"
    }
   </script>
```

Basically the above code *should* pass the post's ID, Likes, and Dislikes to the `Like()` function when I click the `<a>` link. From there, I use the passed `id` to find the document with that same `id` and edit it's `innerHTML` to add 1 to it's `likes`. (I am doing this for my own reasons). But when I click the `<a>` link, nothing happens, no alert. I inspected element and the `<a>` link shows up as `onclick="Like(56ce7a3161714811003ae5f7, 1, 0);"`, which is correct.

However, if I call the function with `onclick="Like(100, likes, dislikes);"` for testing, it works correctly and alerts the amount of likes. Is the `{{id}}` too long? Or is there a problem because there's letters in the id? I don't know what to do from here. I just want to be able to call the `Like` function while passing the post `{{id}}`. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add single quotes around your objectid, e.g. `'56ce7a3161714811003ae5f7'` or `'{{id}}'`

```js
function Like(id, likes, dislikes) {
  alert(id + ','+likes+ ',' + dislikes);
  document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = likes + 1 + " likes | " + dislikes + " dislikes"
}
```

```html
<a onclick="likes=1;dislikes=5;Like('56ce7a3161714811003ae5f7', likes, dislikes);" class="btn btn-like"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up" aria-hidden="true">Click this</span></a>
```